# I have a 4 TB WD Green Drive. It clicks 4 times, then a pause, then 1 more click, but it won't mount

Tags: data-recovery, recovery, hard-drive

I have a 4.0 TB WD Green drive. It was in an enclosure as part of a WD My Book or something like that. It failed on me so I took it out of the enclosure and put it in a new one. I plugged it into my MacBook and it had no partitions and the OS kept trying to get me to initialize it. I downloaded Disk Drill and it immediately saw the lost partition and recovered it with the quick scan in like 20 minutes.

Then I made a HUGE MISTAKE!! My MacBook's hard drive is tiny and the recovered partition was nearly 4.0 TB full. My MacBook only has 2 ports and it needs power constantly because the battery is crap. I knew I needed another hard drive to recover the data to, so I paused the recovery session, closed Disk Drill, unplugged the drive, and plugged in a 4 port USB-C splitter.

And that's why I'm here... I plugged it back in and suddenly it wouldn't mount... I removed the 4 port USB-C splitter and plugged it in raw, still nothing... I feel so stupid because it was a perfect recovery! Disk Drill said it had 0 unreadable sectors and the file structure was perfectly preserved! The drive just spins up, makes 4 clicks, pauses, makes 1 more click, then stops. It never mounts. This is a video of what it looks like https://youtube.com/shorts/r--NpWvlt4w?feature=share. You have to turn the volume way up to hear it. Help please! What should I do next? Is there any hope for this drive?

Comment: How it is connected, still through USB? And destination drive too? All through same USB hub? Is it a *powered* hub, with it's own power brick?

Comment: I tried it through the USB hub, then just raw into the USB port again. The enclosure is powered.

Comment: Either the drive itself or the interface is faulty.

Comment: Then it's internal, the repeated 'tries' are the drive trying to move the heads to the SA but failing to do so.